# How to model really rare events in a single time-series

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, logistic, rare-events

The event of interest happened only 5 times in the last 4 years. My independent variables are the number of results returned by Google Search for specific keywords over time (and per domain of each result).

I want to check if it possible to predict the event a few days/weeks before it happens (again) which could be shown by increased Google results some days before the event occurs. At least, I want to calculate the probability of the event occurring within the next X days.

My questions are the following:

1. Is logistic regression the right way to go for it? I've heard of survival models but have no experience using them. I guess survival analysis is not the proper way to go for it since I do not have many cases (e.g. patients), right?
2. If I use LR, how should I format the dependent variable? Now it's an array of around 1.2K 0s (zeros) mixed with five 1s (ones). If I want to predict the probability of the event happening within the next, say, 7 days, should I fill with 1s the 7 places before each existing 1 in the array (hope this makes sense)?
3. How do I decide on the length of time-window I use? For my application, anything between 2 and 30 days is fine. Given the class imbalance, I guess using a larger window will help. Should I treat this just as another hyper-parameter of the model (along with regularization parameters)?
4. What should I optimize then? Is it better to select model based on log-loss or the f1-score?
5. This leads to the question: how do I cross-validate? Currently, I'm using time ordered folds. I'm training on [t0 - t500], then on [t0-t700] and so on and predicting on the left-out observations. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory

Comment: Are you predicting event-arrival-time as a function of any other parameters? Are they themselves time-series in nature? Or are you just considering time itself to be the only predictor (like in reliability analysis)?

Comment: @AdamO As I wrote above, the independent variables are the number of results returned by Google Search for specific keywords over time (i.e. time-series themselves). So some features are 'total results', 'total results from wikipedia.org' etc. on which I'm calculating rolling Max, Avg, Sum, Variance. This leads to a total of around 6K features.

Comment: @Stergios you simply are not powered to detect anything usable. Any such analyses would be completely exploratory. As a type of exploratory analysis, you can simply inspect which features tended to precede the event of interest by a relatively short interval of time. Logistic regression is also powered by the number of events, and 5 is too small for any purpose.

Comment: @AdamO If I format the dependent variable according to my 2nd point, then the 5 events become 150 (with a window size of 30 days). 150 is around 1% of my total points, so I'd expect that I could make something usable, no?

Comment: @Stergios ah I see where you're coming from. Unfortunately, that reasoning won't hold here. Statistical power doesn't depend on the sample size, it depends on the variability in the outcome. For continuous outcomes, we assume (foolishly) there are no ties (two observations with the same $Y$ value). But when the outcome is binary and rare, the variability is too low. A good rule of thumb is to look at the number of events-per-variable or EPV (see Peduzzi 1996). No matter how you format the outcome, there are only 5 EPV.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Do you have any suggestions for reading up further on this? Would this work for predicting any kind of rare event (e.g. low risk bank portfolio defaults).